# Interpolation with Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question from  my practice exam for the upcoming final. I've worked through it, but I'm unsure about my answer.

Part 1: Find the coefficients of the following interpolating polynomial $P(x) = a_0 + a_1(x_1 - x_0) + a_2(x_2 - x_0)(x_2 - x_1)  $  by solving the matrix:

$$ \underline{\underline{x}} \underline{\alpha}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & x_1-x_0 & 0 \\ 1 & x_2-x_0 & (x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1) \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_0\\a_1\\a_2\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} y_0\\y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}=\vec{y}$$

I simply performed elimination and found the following values for the coefficients:

$a_0 = y_0$

$a_1 = \frac{y_1 - y_0}{x_1-x_0}$

$a_2 = \frac{y_2 - y_0}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)} - \frac{y_1 - y_0}{(x_1-x_0)(x_2 - x_1)}$

Part 2:

Given the points: $P_0 (4,1) , P_1(6,3)$  and $P_2(8,8) $ find the values of the coefficients and give the interpolation polynomial in the form:
$P(x) = b_o + b_1x + bx' $

Here I simply plugged in the numbers into my answer for part one and got:

$a_0 = 1, a_1= 1$ and $a_2 = 3/8$

So my final answer for 2: $1 + x + 3/8 x'$

Part 3:

Under what conditions does the Matrix in part one have a unique solution?

I simply said that the $det(Matrix)$ cannot be zero. Therefore:

$x_0$ cannot equal $x_1$ or $x_2$

Apologies for the awkward wording. I translated this from german.

Comment: I wonder what is $x'$?

Comment: That was given in the question. Im not entirely sure either. I think it might be representing something like (x−x0)(x−x1) and the x' is there to just simplify the expression.

Comment: I think what you mean is to find a quadratic function which passes through 3 points. To do this, I would prefer not to use this interpolation method. Just let $f(x)=ax^2 +bx+c$, and you know that f(4)=1, f(6)=3, f(8)=8. Then you will have linear equations with 3 unknowns, which are a, b and c. Solve a, b and c, and then you can find the function f(x).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I understand that your method might be more efficient, but this practice exam explicitly required us to work with the given matrix. In addition, if I solve the problem the way you suggested I get different values for the coefficients.

Comment: the coefficient is different that should be true because my method is $ax^2+bx+c$ and your method is $1+x+\frac{3}{8}(x-x0)(x-x1)$, when you expand $\frac{3}{8}(x-x0)(x-x1)$ and you will find that the coefficient of x and constant term has changed. So different result is found.

Comment: Just put the answer into the equation, and see if the function passes through the 3 points given, to check that your answer is correct or not using my approach and your approach. I suppose both approach will give a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The interpolating polynomial $P(x)$ should have been $$P(x)=a_0+a_1(x-x_0)+a_2(x-x_0)(x-x_1)$$ The linear system you obtained is the result of the fact that $P(x_0)=y_0$, $P(x_1)=y_1$ and $P(x_2)=y_2$.

You are right in saying that the solution is unique when the determinant is nonzero. But the matrix is a triangular matrix and so its determinant is simply the product of its diagonal elements: $$\det A=(x_1-x_0)(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)$$ This is nonzero when all $x_0, x_1$ and $x_2$ are distinct.